# Most cost effective way to power a bunch op amps +/-12V supply rails from +5V

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, cost

I'm searching for the most cost effective way to supply +/-12V for 12 TL084 op amps. Reading in the datasheet, it seems they have a typical current output (with load) of about 20mA. So, 12 * 20 = 240mA. Assuming that is correct, I only need about 300mA of current draw from the +/-12V supply.

Here are the solutions I've come across:

- Recom Power - RS6-0512D: This modules takes in 5V and provides +/-12V output. Pretty straight forward but a bit pricy, around 21$CAD.
- Using 1 TC1044S charge pump per 2 op amps and an external 5V to 12V boost converter for the whole deal. Total cost: 1.45$CAD (TC1044) * 6 = 8,70$. Add around 4$ for the 5V to 12V converter = 12,70$CAD for the whole thing.

Any simple solution I haven't thought of? Are these 2 solutions a standard way to power a bunch of signal processing op-amps? Is it a problem even worth solving with a chip or should I go down the road of implementing this myself? Is there even any advantages to implement this myself?

Comment: Asking for recommendations of specific products is not allowed on this site.

Comment: Ok, I'll rephrase the question a bit.

Comment: What i really want to know is not really a specific product but rather if the path I'm looking to take makes sense as I don't really know any other routes.

Comment: Is cost your biggest constraint?  Do you have board space constraints area or height?

Comment: Also, how are your solder skills/abilities?

Comment: Yep, I got space to spare on my main board which would provide those supply lines to smaller boards with the op amps. 

Regarding soldering skills, I solder very tiny SMD parts no problem.

Comment: Basically, yes, cost is the main constaint.

Comment: Are you sure you need +/-12V supplies? What is your signal level? What is your output load? If you really need to support 20 volts peak to peak and up to 20mA output current from each op-amp you have a very strange application.

Answer (score 2):

One way to tackle this is to implement a boost regulator with two outputs - one inverted, and one non-inverted - such as the [TI TPS65130](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps65130.pdf).  It's about US$3 / qty. 1 on Digikey, and you'll probably need a few dollars for passives.

[image: TPS65130]

Make sure to have decoupling caps (0.1 uF) and bulk caps (4.7 ~ 10 uF) at each op-amp supply pin.  If you have low-noise requirements, you can set the boost regulator to +/- 15 V and add +/-12 V LDOs on the outputs.

Comment: Nice alternative. I'll check this out.

Comment: @KévinIsabelle Great!  You may want to leave the question open a bit longer (reclick the green check mark) to see if this will work for your application.  Also, someone else (perhaps perusing the Unanswered questions) may chime in with alternatives.

Comment: And actually, I've juste checked the price-tag to build this kind of assembly, and it is very close to my solution #2 in terms of price, but more complicated. I see where you were going with the soldering as it is a VQFN package with no leads. Feasible but a bit of a pain for me at prototyping stage.